# Get urls in views.py - python django

Tags: python, django

my urls.py

```
url(r'^ACB/(?P<slug>.*)/$', views.ACB.as_view(), name='ACB'),
```

I have requirement where I need to send this url for couple of random slug as part of a response for an API

I do not want the url of request but url of different view

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: That is not very clear. Do you want the url of the request in your `ACB` view ?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reverse`

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

my_url = reverse('ACB')
```

This would reverse the `ACB` url without any argument. If slug is present, you can pass it in `args`:

```
my_url = reverse('ACB', args=(slug,))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: I would just update this with `my_url = reverse('ACB', args=(slug, ))` if present, as slug is an optional argument.

Comment: It's amazing how you are able to get what OP wants. I still have trouble understanding his question.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021 (Django 2.0+)

In Django 2.0, the module `django.core.urlresolvers` was moved to `django.urls`.

New solution to question:

```
from django.urls import reverse

my_url = reverse('ACB')
my_url = reverse('ACB', args=(slug,))
```

For further information, see:

- [ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139081/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-urlresolvers)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.9/#features-deprecated-in-1-9