# ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-3.5, django-2.0

I am working on Django project where I need to create a form for inputs. I tried to import `reverse` from `django.core.urlresolvers`. I got an error:

```
line 2, in from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

I am using Python 3.5.2, Django 2.0 and MySQL.

Comment: looks like django is not installed on your PATH.

Answer (score 499, accepted):

Django 2.0 removes the `django.core.urlresolvers` module, which was moved to `django.urls` in version 1.10. You should change any import to use [django.urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) instead, like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

Note that Django 2.0 removes some features that previously were in `django.core.urlresolvers`, so you might have to make some more changes before your code works. See the [features deprecated in 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.9/#features-deprecated-in-1-9) for details on those additional changes.

Comment: I have this error in a third party module: how can I solve? I could edit the module but what then when I upgrade a new uncorrected version? Is it possible to override?

Comment: You could update and send a pull request to the third party module

Answer (score 68):

if you want to import reverse, import it from `django.urls`

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

Answer (score 31):

You need replace all occurrences of:

`from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`

to:

`from django.urls import reverse`

[image]

**NOTE: The same apply to reverse_lazy**

in Pycharm <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  for starting replacment in Path.

Comment: I got same error, tried this and now get error  File "C:\Users\displ\Code\.virtualenvs\dev\lib\site-packages\cms\utils\i18n.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver, LocaleRegexURLResolver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers', had to do what correct answer said replace all references. Django kind of sucks though, lot of stuff doesn't work from get go.

Answer (score 8):

use **from django.urls import reverse** instead of **from  django.core.urlresolvers import reverse**

Answer (score 3):

For those who might be trying to create a Travis Build, the default path from which Django is installed from the `requirements.txt` file points to a repo whose `django_extensions` module has not been updated. The only workaround, for now, is to install from the master branch using pip. That is where the patch is made. But for now, we'll have to wait.

You can try this in the meantime, it might help

`- pip install git+https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions.git@master`

`- pip install git+https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions.git@master`

Answer (score 3):

For django version greater than 2.0 use:

```py
from django.urls import reverse
```

in your models.py file.

Answer (score 2):

urlresolver has been removed in the higher version of Django - Please upgrade your django installation. I fixed it using the following command.

```
pip install django==2.0 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading Django 1.9 (Python 2.7) to Django 3.2 (Python 3.9)

This could be solved in a one line bash replacement:

```
grep -ril "from django.core.urlresolvers" your_source_code_folder | xargs sed -i 's@from django.core.urlresolvers@from django.urls@g'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your builds on TravisCI are failing for this particular reason, you can resolve the issue by updating the Django Extensions in your requirements.txt

```
pip install --upgrade django-extensions
```

This will update the extensions to use Django 2+ modules.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this either you down-grade the `Django` to any version lesser than `2.0.
pip` install `Django==1.11.29`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had outdated `django-stronghold` installed (0.2.9). And even though in the code I had:

```py
from django.urls import reverse
```

I still encountered the error. After I upgraded the version to `django-stronghold==0.4.0` the problem disappeard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but that was just because of my url.py file.
I fixed it like below:

```
from drf_spectacular.views import (
SpectacularAPIView,
SpectacularSwaggerView,
)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema',),
    path('api/docs/',  SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-docs',),
]
```