# Have updated the django-rest-framework to last version, why there still have the `No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'` error?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Have updated the django-rest-framework to last version, why there still have the error?

> ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'

From the post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330759/7646621

I have update the djangorestframework to the version `3.8.2`.

But the issue still exists.

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework_docs/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework_docs.views import DRFDocsView
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework_docs/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rest_framework_docs.api_docs import ApiDocumentation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework_docs/api_docs.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLResolver, RegexURLPattern
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

my Django version is `Version: 2.0.6`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade rest_framework_docs as well.

Comment: I don't know what package you did install. However, the stack trace points to some rest_framework_docs namespace which is *not* part of the regular Django REST framework which means you have installed an incompatible 3rd party.

Comment: I updated, but this is the last version of `drfdocs`. seems some people still have this issue on GitHub.https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-docs/issues/175

Answer (score 1):

From the drfdocs https://www.drfdocs.com/installation/:

you can upgrade it by:

```
pip install --upgrade drfdocs
```