# File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, django-shop

Trying out Django Shop. Following this tutorial: https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/intro.html (stable).

When I run the server and open localhost, here's what I see:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables.
       Parent style sheet: /home/vm/PycharmProjects/Django-shop/django-shop/shop/static/shop/css/_variables.scss
        on line 1 of ../shop/static/shop/css/_variables.scss
>> @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
```

I presume, this "bootstrap-sass" directory is supposed to be in "css" and I don't see it there.

Only happens on front of the website. I can open admin panel just fine.

Comment: Can you try this `python manage.py collectstatic` and then see if the error goes away. It looks like the static files related to Django Shop are not present in static folder.

Comment: @Paandittya This is weird. It says ```No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```. Reinstalling Django didn't help

Comment: Ok. Now this sounds like you are using a version of Django Shop which is not compatible with your Django version. Could you take a look at [Compatibility Table](https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#django-python-compatibility-table) from docs of Django Shop and confirm that there is no conflict in your setup?

Comment: @Paandittya You're right. I'm using the Django version 2.1.7. Downgraded it to 1.11 and now it works just fine. Thank you =) Are you going to write an answer below? Or should I answer my own question?

Comment: Added as the answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mentioned in the comment that says `No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'` gives you a clue that there is a django compatibility issue. To understand more about this error please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139407/7636315) answer on Stackoverflow, which discusses a particular changelog from Django 1.x version to 2.x.
Now that we know that this could be a point of conflict here, refer to [Compatibility Table](https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#django-python-compatibility-table), which clearly states that Django Shop is not compatible with Django 2.x versions as of now and in your project setup when you `pip install django`, it installs the latest version of django which is 2.1. Therefore to overcome this, you should downgrade the Django to a version thats compatible with your Django Shop version. So a working combination would be Django 1.11 and Django Shop 0.13.x.