# django locale-url import error cannot import name 'urlresolvers' from 'django.core'

Tags: python, django, django-localeurl

I am working through [docs](https://django-localeurl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html?fbclid=IwAR2dPHgFCwS_zRCws9zgVKgnxAWu-2mt7UpCx2Hn4YVhdJM8MriNCWx5Vbg#configuration)

This is the import statement:

```py
from django.core import urlresolvers
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlresolvers' from 'django.core'
(xxx/nbrl-project/nbrlenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/__init__.py)
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139081/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-urlresolvers) thread. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139081/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-urlresolvers)

Comment: no sir its not helping. i have already tried this. error is coming from localeurl/models/py where reverse is not imported

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the provided docs:

> localeurl application requires Django 1.3 or higher and Python 2.6 or
> 2.7.

You are probably using a higher version of django. Since version 2.0, the `django.core.urlresolvers` module has been moved to `django.urls`

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

If possible, keep your django at the latest version, since version 1.3 is no longer supported.

Comment: Note that Django 1.3 is from 2011, not maintained anymore - "beyond old". If you have the choice, especially if you start a new project - do not use it anymore. Last commit of https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/commits/ is from 2015, it is not maintained anymore. Django offers already built-in ways to reflect the language in the url.

Comment: does this mean localeurl is not good to use? can you suggest me some other library of such

Comment: Yes @Risadinha. Use an older django version isn't recommended due to lack of support and of course, security.

Comment: @avigiri Django can handle this, check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new project, you should go for Django's own URL internationalization: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization

Try not to use un-maintained versions of Django and any other library, if you can help it. This will spare you a load of trouble.

Citing from the docs that you have linked (https://django-localeurl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> Warning
>
> django-localeurl is currently un-maintained (so pull requests will not
> be reviewed or merged), and its approach has been obsoleted by the
> introduction of locale-aware URL patterns in Django itself. If you are
> nonetheless interested in taking over maintenance of django-localeurl,
> please file an issue to volunteer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try delete `"allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",` from setting.py if you using `django-allauth` and configure it correctly