# How to deal with django-subdomains in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

Hello everyone I am in the progress of upgrading Django from 1.11 to 2.0.

I have run into an issue with the django-subdomains package, where it is attempting to import from django.core.urlresolvers. It looks like this package is no longer maintained.

Editing the files in the library is not an option, so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for an alternative that I can switch over to relatively easily.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340968/django-locale-url-import-error-cannot-import-name-urlresolvers-from-django-co/63341291#63341291

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing django-subdomains and installing [this](https://subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) fork.

```
pip install subdomains
```